# Remote with WMI for JDBC Connector: Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: c#, jdbc, jvm, wmi, connector

I got a batch file which start up a JDBC connector with command below:

```
java -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:NewRatio=1 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m  -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0 
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:+UseTLAB -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=240000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=240000 -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16\jre"\lib;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16\jre"\lib\ext
```

com.fastsearch.esp.connectors.jdbc.JDBCConnector %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7

It works fine if I start it up on the PC locally, but it gives me "Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap" when I run it remotely with WMI in C#.

Here is the C# code I have used:

```
ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions(null,System.TimeSpan.MaxValue,true);
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass
    (manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
inParams["CommandLine"] = @"D:\temp\connect.bat";
inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"D:\temp";
ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

So is there any concern when I work with JVM remotely?  Is there any memory limit when I use WMI on remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: https://www.anoopcnair.com/configmgr-sccm-how-to-increase-wmi-default-memory-allocation/

I need to increase the WMI Process memory to a certain amount in order to get that JDBC Connector running. The default is 128MB, which is not enough for the Connector setup.  Just too much trouble... I give up.  I am going to use psExec instead.